# How to develop for old versions of excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm developing excel based solutions for companies that have old versions of excel as their standard.

What is the best way to develop using vba and formulas and knowing that it will work in different versions of excel? It's not easy to have all possible versions installed in your computer.

Thanks!!

Comment: It's actually not that hard to have all MS supported versions installed at once but you can also use virtual machines.

Comment: @Rory how do you do that? (without installing virtual machines). Microsft usually doen't allow you to have two or more versions of the same program.

Comment: Install oldest to newest. You need licences for each and you can't easily mix 32 and 64 bit (not at all for the same Office version). Also you can only have one click to run version at a time.

Comment: I have 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016 all on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save your workbook as a binary workbook (.xlsb) you will have nearly all of the functionality of the modern .xlsx, with the added functionality of macros. These will open just fine under Excel 2003. As a bonus the file size of .xlsb spreadsheets are smaller, which is one reason I tend to use this extension when working with Excel. Just check that the formulas you use are available in their Excel version(s).

Comment: Many VSTO extensions are incompatible and require modern formats.